# Moving data between identical database schema's in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, migration

I have 2 databases with identical schemas. One is a master database serving production/marketing purposes (probably 95% SELECTs) and the other is a "slave" and runs SELECTs/INSERTs for orders, customers, etc for a specific micro-site.

The reason for the separation is not all micro-sites will run the same products/specials/coupons etc and an API is in the works, but it won't be completed for some time.

I need to move data from the slave/micro-site database to the master database and maintain key associations.

Example: 
Master database has orders #1 and #2 (on orders.id let's say) and I have several new orders on my micro-site database that I want to get migrated to the master database so production/manufacturing can begin processing those orders.

How can I move that data using in the easiest way to avoid conflicts/duplicate keys?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily [disable foreign key checks](http://gauravsohoni.wordpress.com/2009/03/09/mysql-disable-foreign-key-checks-or-constraints/) during the copy.

Or do you need to copy them while keeping all constraints in place?

Comment: I need to copy them while keeping restraints in place. I just essentially need to insert everything from the slave into the master as if it's fresh data.

Comment: Having read Wrikken's response I realize I probably misinterpreted the problem.  I think he's got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 databases, and (auto-increment) primary keys should not overlap, the easiest way to achieve it is to set [`auto_increment_increment` & `auto_increment_offset`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset).

Master:

```
auto_increment_increment = 2
autoincrement-offset = 1
```

Copy yet to be merged:

```
auto_increment_increment = 2
auto_increment_offset = 2
```

Now, all 'freshly' inserted records with an auto-increment key will guaranteed not overlap. Copying data from one to another (i.e: with a defined key/id) will just insert that id, making it easy to copy 'standalone' data like orders to the other database. If you are however *altering* data with the same primary keys (copy product#1 from master to copy, altering product#1 on copy, and then trying to copy product#1 back to the master as a distinctly different product), then you'll have to write a moderately sofisticated import script which knows all about you primary keys & relations and reassigns them. Possibly you can do this without to much script if it is about 2 databases on 1 server, with carefully crafted temporary tables etc, but there is no 'fire & forget' method out of the box I know of.